# How to use onAcitivtyResult into some fragments int Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

In my application i have one `activity` (**MainActivity**) and some `fragments` (**ServicesFragment** , **NewAddressFragment**).
**ServicesFragment** used in `viewPager` and **NewAddressFragment** used `getFragmentManager().replace ...` for show this `fragments`!
in this `fragments` i used `onActivityResult`, but get conflict in one of `fragments` **not call** codes of `onActivityResult` codes in one of `fragments`.
I write below codes, please see this.
**MainActivity :**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment servicesFrag = bottomNavAdapter.getItem(mainViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    if (servicesFrag instanceof ServicesFragment) {
        ((ServicesFragment) servicesFrag).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**ServiceFragment :**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.e("BazaarPaymentLog", "Result");
    Log.e("BazaarPaymentLog", "bazaarRequestCode : " + bazaarRequestCode);
    if (iabHelper == null) return;

    if (requestCode == bazaarRequestCode) {
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                purchaseToken = jo.getString("purchaseToken");
                productId = jo.getString("productId");
                packageName = jo.getString("packageName");

                Log.e("BazaarPaymentLog", "purchaseToken : " + purchaseToken);
                if (iabHelper != null) {
                    iabHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**NewAddressFragment :**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) {
            if (data != null) {
                // Get the Image from data
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                assert cursor != null;
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                postPath = mediaPath;
                uploadImageToServer(postPath);
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {
                postPath = mImageFileLocation;
            } else {
                postPath = fileUri.getPath();
            }
            uploadImageToServer(postPath);
        }
    } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

When write `onActivityResult` code in `MainActivity`, in `ServicesFragment` **call** `onActivityResult` codes and in `NewAddressFragment` **not call** `onActivityResult` codes.

But When remove `onActivityResult` code in `MainActivity`, in `ServicesFragment` **not call** `onActivityResult` codes and in `NewAddressFragment` **call** `onActivityResult` codes.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolved my problem!
**Change MainActivity codes with below codes :**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment servicesFrag = bottomNavAdapter.getItem(mainViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    Fragment addressFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("NewAddressFragmentTag");
    if (servicesFrag instanceof ServicesFragment) {
        ((ServicesFragment) servicesFrag).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    if (addressFrag instanceof NewAddressFragment) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I hope help this for another dear developers

Answer (score 3):

Inside onActivityResult of MainActivity use this :

Instead of this :-

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Fragment servicesFrag = bottomNavAdapter.getItem(mainViewPager.getCurrentItem());
if (servicesFrag instanceof ServicesFragment) {
    ((ServicesFragment) servicesFrag).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Use this :-

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    for(Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()){
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }

}
```

let me know if it is working or not

Comment: not found fragment in supportFragmentManager.fragments and show me error! for this you use Kotlin? please send to me true code. i am amateur and really need your help. please

Comment: when use this code, not call onActivityResult of NewAddressFragment codes!

Comment: in ServicesFragment call codes, but in NewAddressFragment not call

Comment: add log in NewAddressFragment same as ServiceFragment before if condition then check.

Answer (score 0):

please add this line to onActivityResult in activity

```
    Fragment servicesFrag = bottomNavAdapter.getItem(mainViewPager.getCurrentItem());
 Fragment addressFrag = findFragmentByTag("NewAddressFragmentTag");
 if (servicesFrag instanceof ServicesFragment) {
 ((ServicesFragment) servicesFrag).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
 if (addressFrag instanceof NewAddressFragment) {
 ((NewAddressFragment) addressFrag).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
 }
```

Comment: thanks dear but not found super.onActivityResult . how can i use this? can you send to me full code with my above codes? (mamnoon misham komakam konid mohammad jan)

Comment: thanks dear but not found super.onActivityResult . how can i use this? can you send to me full code with my above codes? (mamnoon misham komakam konid mohammad jan)

Comment: Vaqti az in code estefade mikonam onActivityResulte marboot be ServicesFragment call nemishe!

Comment: if (servicesFrag instanceof ServicesFragment) in javabesh true hast?

Comment: bale, age mese in benevisam ok hast. vali oonvaqt dg vase NewAddressFragment kar nemikone!

Comment: az koje mikhay NewAddressFragment ro seda bezani?

Comment: Man ye Activity kolli daram ke chandin Fragment dare. ServiceFragment tooye viewPager hast o NewAddressFragment az ye fragment dg ba click baz mishe. codesh ham ine :  `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.newAddressContent, new NewAddressFragment(),"NewAddressFragmentTag").commit();`

Comment: khob chera ye if dige bara if (servicesFrag instanceof NewAddressFragmentTag) nemizari

Comment: Intori? : 
        `Fragment servicesFrag = bottomNavAdapter.getItem(mainViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        Fragment addressFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("NewAddressFragmentTag");
        if (servicesFrag instanceof ServicesFragment) {
            ((ServicesFragment) servicesFrag).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        if (addressFrag instanceof NewAddressFragment) {
            ((NewAddressFragment) addressFrag).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }` . zadam vali kar nakard!

Comment: rah kare dgii be zehnetoon nemirese?

Comment: man hamon avali ro ke mizaram harchi ke bala bashe ro seda mizane

Comment: nemidoonam vala khodamam moondam chera intori mikone!

Comment: be nazaram haminam moshkeli nadare